# Why didn't sleep working like usleep in mutithread on linux?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

In the following program,if I replace the usleep with sleep(0.5),then it won't sleep as the usleep,what is the reason behind this?
I tried to search but find no answer.This happens both in my Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 8.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void*  mmmm(void* args){
        int i=0;
        while(i<1000){
                printf("A:%d\n",i);
                i++;
                usleep(500000);
        //      sleep(0.5);
        }
        return NULL;
}
void* nnnn(void* args){
        int j=1000;
        while(j>0){
                printf("B:%d\n",j);
                j--;
                usleep(500000);
//              sleep(0.5);
        }
        return NULL;
}
int main(){
        pthread_t a,b;
        int errora = pthread_create(&a,NULL,mmmm,NULL);
        int errorb = pthread_create(&b,NULL,nnnn,NULL);
        printf("error A:%d,error B:%d\n",errora,errorb);

        int status_a,status_b;
        pthread_join(b,(void*)&status_b);
        pthread_join(a,(void*)&status_a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sleep takes an unsigned int. What would be the resulting value when you supply it with 0.5? You might want to turn on your compiler warnings -W -Wall

Comment: Functions don't change their declared parameter types just because the programmer wish them to. Just like a vending machine selling a snack bar for $1 coin won't give you half a snack bar if you show a 50 cent coin into the dollar coin slot.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter to sleep is unsigned int seconds. 0.5 generates warning and assumes 0

"man 3 sleep":

unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

Comment: Wow！I got it.Thank you very much.